# Mapping with to Shemas with Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have two tables in the same server (MSSMQL) with two differents  schema the target ( [dbo].[Reserv])and the source ([staging].[Reserv])
I've tried to do a mapping ( Source to target)  to filed the bdo from Staging.

the schema of the Target :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Reserv](
             [SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
             [ResourceType] [varchar](10) NULL,
             [ResourceTableName] [varchar](100) NULL
             )
```

The schema of the Source :

```
CREATE TABLE [staging].[Reserv](
             [SourceID] [int] NOT NULL,
             [ReType] [varchar](10) NULL,
             )
```

I have a rule  for the 'ResourceTableName' -> ** ResType= 'A' then' Em'
ResType='En' then'En'**

what I have done in my stored procedure to insert , But did not work with me:

```
....
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                        INSERT
                        (
                             [SourceID] 
                            ,[ResourceType]
                            ,[ResourceTableName]
                            
                        )
                        VALUES
                        (
                             7
                             ,SOURCE.[ResourceType]
                             ,CASE WHEN SOURCE.[ResourceType]=''A'' THEN INSERT ''Em'' ELSE INSERT ''En'' END
    
                             );';
```

Thanks

Comment: Without context this makes little sense. But CASE in tsql is an expression that returns a scalar value. Your very abbreviated code (which seems to be tsql) is logically flawed and will generate a syntax error if you attempt to use it as a control-of-flow construct. Did you encounter an error? Is that what you mean by "did not work"? If so, post the complete error message and a complete (if reduced) code that generates the error.

Comment: SMor , i edit my question hops that more clear ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert the rows with `case` logic:

```
insert into target (SourceID, ResourceType, ResourceTableName)
    select s.SourceID, s.ResourceType,
           (CASE WHEN s.[ResourceType] = 'Agent' THEN 'Employee' ELSE 'Engin' END)
    from source s;
```

If this is not what you mean, then I don't understand "mapping".